# 'focus fully on' or 'fully focus on'

Tags: grammaticality, differences, adverbs

A student wrote '(I) focused fully on cycling'. I am quite certain about 'I fully focused on' but I think his phrasing was grammatically correct too.

Answer (score 1):

He was fully {focused on cycling} and thus didn't hear the car accident.

He was {focused} fully on cycling and wasn't focused on anything else.

Comment: Yes, these are idiomatic. But OP doesn't mention these sentences. And are you claiming a distinction between 'was fully focused on' and 'was focused fully on'? // [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+focused+fully+on%2Che+fully+focused+on%2Che+was+focused+fully+on%2Che+was+fully+focused+onon&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20focused%20fully%20on%3B%2Cc0) may help here.